# How to recursively add text to a data frame output from lapply?

Tags: r

I'm writing a small piece of code that takes two different data frames and compare the content in each of them. How to access the individual rows in data frame when using lapply ?

I tried using nested for loops to access the indexes. However the data set is very large and is taking a very long time to execute.

```
for (i in 1:20){
for(j in 1:nrow(keyFile)){
        consolFile[i,46] <- 
ifelse(str_detect(toString(consolFile[i,47]),toString(keyFile[j,1])),append(toString(consolFile[i,46]),paste(";",toString(keyFile[j,1]))),append(toString(consolFile[i,46]),""))

  }

}
```

I basically am trying to append the matched content with a semi colon and the next matched element. I heard lapply/apply are faster ways of achieveing this. But I'm unable to access the individual rows to append the data.

If dataframe 1 has

```
1.abc
2.def
3.bdc
```

and if dataframe 2 has

```
1.a
2.b
```

the output should be

```
1.a;b
2.
3.b
```

Comment: have you checked the answers?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I have an exhaustive solution to the problem of appending the results, but this is what I've got:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- data.frame(words = c("abc", "def", "bdc"), stringsAsFactors = F) 
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = F) 



map(1:nrow(df2), function(x) str_extract(df1[,1], df2[x,1])) %>%
  pmap(paste, sep = ";") %>%
  map(str_remove_all, "NA;|;NA|NA") %>%
  do.call("rbind", .) %>%
  cbind(df1, "matches" = .)

  words matches
1   abc     a;b
2   def        
3   bdc       b
```

```` purrr::map``` is almost the same as ````lapply()`, you could exchange it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This uses `str_extract_all` and the fact that you can collapse your search vector with | (i.e., search for `'a|b'`). I leave some extra columns but it would be easy for you to get the output you want.

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56251378/how-to-recursively-add-text-to-a-data-frame-output-from-lapply

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tib <- tibble(x = c('abc', 'def', 'bdc'))

match_vector <- c('a','b')
paste(match_vector, collapse = '|')

tib%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(matches = str_extract_all(x, 'a|b') #could use match_vector and collapse here
         ,matches2 = paste(matches, collapse = ';'))%>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     matches   matches2
  <chr> <list>    <chr>   
1 abc   <chr [2]> a;b     
2 def   <chr [0]> ""      
3 bdc   <chr [1]> b
```